# spring mvc view not rendered

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

I'm a beginner in spring mvc and trying to create very basic web app flow. I have **result.jsp** which by clicking on submit should render **submit.jsp**. I can see the controller is invoked but my view **submit.jsp** is not being rendered. It gives me `HTTP 404` status error with no logs in tomcat. Can someone please help me to figure out what went wrong here.

I also observe when running the app, i am being directed to
    `testspring/` where i see my result.jsp. I rather expected it to be
    `testspring/result.jsp` on running the app. Please pardon my ignorance.

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>testspring</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>frontcontrol</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>frontcontrol</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

frontcontrol-servlet.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package ="com.shell.spring.testspringapp">
</context:component-scan>

<bean id ="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">

    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />      
</bean>
```

Controller class- Frontcontrol

```
@Controller
public class Firstcontrol {

    @RequestMapping(value="/")
    public ModelAndView invokeme(Model m) {

        ModelAndView mav=new ModelAndView();
        mav.setViewName("result");
        System.out.println("In invoke me method");
        return mav;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/submit" ,method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String submit(Model m) {
        System.out.println("In submitmethod");
        return "submit";
    }
}
```

Comment: Replace '/' by '*' for `url-pattern` In your web.xml file.

Comment: REPLACE <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> WITH  <url-pattern>*.*</url-pattern> JUST FOR TESTING AND IF IT IS WORKING AND YOU WANT URL PATTERN LIKE ABC.HTM THEN PUT <url-pattern>*.HTM</url-pattern>

Comment: @AbhendraSingh no luck. When i run the app it gives me http 404 error.

Comment: @JOHND It gives me the same http 404 error

Comment: SEE YOUR FIRST REQUEST MAPPING @RequestMapping(value="/")

Comment: YOU MAKE IT AS @RequestMapping(value="/submit")

Comment: Are you including the context path in your URL?  The context is generally the name of your WAR file that is being deployed (or WAR folder, if you are deploying exploded).

Comment: Also, I don't see a RequestMapping on your controller.  You typically want one there, too.

Comment: @Jasu Are you able to go to your controller? Please check on tomcat logs that it is showing comment that you have printed in controller. like('In submitmethod' or 'In invoke me method'). If you are not able to reach your controller then you can't go to view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments - yo should update your web.xml so it maps * through to your servlet:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>frontcontrol</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

You can adjust this later if you want to limit the available mappings, but will do for now.

After that, we need to see the `result.jsp` (my understanding from your question is that this page renders ok when you hit the root of your webapp, so this controller call & view is roking ok).  However, an educated guess for some things you can check:

- What is the url on the button you are pressing? is it relative? e.g. is it "`submit`"  or is it "`/submit`" - the latter will cut out your app context. For example, if your app the root of your app is `http://localhost:8080/testspring` then using the url `/submit` will direct you to `http://localhost:8080/submit` - so not hitting your spring app and will just 404 straight away
- What element is the submit button? is it a button or a href? If it is a button, what method are you using? this needs to match the method on the controller - on the controller you are only matching against `GET` requests to the url submit - if your button is `POSTing` then this method won't be hit.

To answer your final point - yes, it will render as `testspring/` rather than `testspring/result.jsp` - this is because you are using an mvc framework and not just hitting the files on the system - e.g. the request has hit the root url (`/`) which is handled by the controller which in turn renders a view - the view could be one jsp or made up of several files (using tiles etc) or something else - you are not "hitting" the jsp directly, rather the jsp is being used by the controller when serving up the path "/"

Comment: Thanks a lot :) This works now by just retaining the url-pattern "/". The issue was my form action had an incorrect reference  :( . And thanks for your neat explanation on rendering view.